# delete list based on label in shiny + R

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am new to R and Shiny, so is not aware of advanced shiny and R widgets/programming.

I am creating lists in Shiny if Add list button is clicked.List are labelled "List 1", "List 2". It works fine.

I have multiple delete button corresponding to each added list with labels like "Delete List 1", "Delete List 2" etc.

How can I specifically delete a list, for example, when I click on Delete List 3, only that specific list 3 needs to be deleted.

My code right now deletes the latest list added, no matter which button is clicked. My code is as follows:

```
    for(x in 1:length(uiElements)){

               uiElements <- deleteElements(x,input,uiElements)
     }

deleteElements <- function(x,input,uiElements){

        cntr <- GetCounter()
    uiLabel <- paste("List",x,sep=" ")
    delLabel <- paste("Delete",uiLabel,sep=" ")
    if(!is.null(input[[delLabel]]) && input[[delLabel]] > 0 && cntr> 1){
            cntr <- cntr - 1
            SetCounter(cntr)
            uiElements <- uiElements[-which(uiElements==uiLabel)]

    }
    return (uiElements)
```

}

I understand why the latest one is deleted, its based on how my loop is. But I have no idea how to specifically delete the clicked one. May be there is some better built-in functions to use.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.